# Application of Differential Equations Logistics problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, word-problem, related-rates

Problem:
The rate of change of the total number of sales, $dS(t)\over dt$, of a new product is proportional to $ S(t)\over t^2$, where $t$ is in years. If the saturation of the market is $50000$ units, and if after $1$ year the total numbr of sales is $10000$ units, find the number of sales at any time $t$.

I have tried solving this problem by setting it up as follows

$$\frac{dS(t)}{dt} = k \frac{S(t)}{t^2}$$

I come to the answer of
$S(t)$ = $ce^{-\frac{k}{t}}  $ or $\ln(S(t)) = -\frac{k}{t} + \ln(c)$

This allows me to solve for $c$ getting $ \ln(c)= \ln(10000) + k$

However, even if I subsitute this back in for $c$ and try to solve for $k$ I am out of given data. Am I doing the problem wrong or what have I missed. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The saturation of the market is the total number of sales as $t\to\infty$. Taking this limit in your solution, we find
$$
50000=\lim_{t\to\infty}S(t)=c. \tag{1}
$$
Now we can find $k$ by plugging $t=1$ in the equation $\ln(S(t))=-\frac{k}{t}+\ln(c)$:
$$
\ln(10000)=-k+\ln(50000) \implies k=\ln(5). \tag{2}
$$

Comment: Why is the equation ln(c) instead of just + c?

Comment: That's how logarithms work:
$$S(t)=ce^{−k/t}\implies \ln(S(t))=\ln(c)+\ln(e^{−k/t})=\ln(c)−kt.$$
If you want to replace $\ln(c)$
 with $C$
 on the RHS, then you also have to replace $c$
 with $e^C$
 on the LHS.